# Set the entry of a node in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a force layout built using d3.js with nodes entering at interval of 15 seconds. When the nodes enter, they enter from any random direction before settling in the center. I want the node to enter always from left top (0,0) and then go to the center to settle.

```
that.force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-8.6)
    .linkDistance(2)
    .size([600, 600]);

that.svg = d3.select(that.selector).append("svg")
    .attr("width", that.width)
    .attr("height", that.height);

d3.json("data/tweets.json", function(error, graph) {
  that.graph = graph;
setInterval(function () {
  d3.json("data/tweets.json", function(error, graph) {
    that.graph = graph;
    that.render();
  });
},15000);

that.force
    .nodes(that.graph.nodes)
    .links(that.graph.links)
    .start(0);


that.nodes = that.svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(that.graph.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .call(that.force.drag);


that.nodes
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("width", that.rectw)
    .attr("height", that.recth)
    .style("fill","white")
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.COLOR; })
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")

that.nodes.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.SCREEN_NAME; });

that.nodes.append("image")
    .attr("class", "node-image")
    .attr("transform", "translate(1,1)")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "img/"+d.PROFILE_PIC;})
    .attr("height", that.rectw-2 + "px")
    .attr("width", that.recth-2 + "px");

that.link = that.svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(that.graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

that.force.on("tick", function() {
  that.link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  that.nodes.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")";
  })
});
});
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to post your code so that we can comb through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-set the position of the nodes before giving them to the force layout by setting the `x` and `y` attributes of the data. So in your case, all you need to do is initialise `x` and `y` of all nodes to 0.

Comment: So do i need to change my data from 
{"nodes":[{"name":"abc"}],"links":[]} to
{"nodes":[{"name":"abc","x":0,"y":0}],"links":[]}

Comment: You can either do that or loop through your nodes after loading the JSON and set those attributes.

Comment: That works. Thanks again. Also is it possible to create a curve path instead of linear path for the node going from 0,0 to the center?

Comment: You would have to modify how the force layout works for this or do the path to the center before inserting the node into the force layout. Neither of those options are particularly easy.

Comment: Will i find any example over the net for this particulat requirement

Comment: I'm not aware of any examples that do this.